# 3D printing of alumina

Tags: physical-chemistry, hydrocarbons, surface-chemistry, ceramics

I want to print a structure of alumina, and the 3D printer that I am using is an extrusion-based printer. So I need your help in knowing that what composition (binders and deflocculant) of alumina will be suitable to print the 3D structure in such a manner that it holds its structure (as it is printed)? And to what extent should rheological properties be maintained so that structure doesn't fail?

Comment: How are you going to turn the slurry into a solid? Existing processes for similar things (eg Saffil fibres) require rapidly heating the slurry in a furnace.

Answer (score 1):

Use methylcellulose(MC) as a binder and Ammonium Polyacrylate (NHPA) as your dispersant or deflocculant. The concentration of methylcellulose can be set according to your requirement as its non-ionic (if you want liquid slurry use MC in large amount and if you don't use less amount). For NHPA you have to make different samples of fixed alumina concentration and NHPA of different concentrations. Check viscosity of each sample and the one which gives you least viscosity means the best-dispersed sample and hence your operating concentration of NHPA.